# Rails3: form_for/simple_form_for record values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

How can I read record parameters from the form object (@banner.name)?

```
= simple_form_for @banner |f|
  = f.name
  ...
  = f.simple_fields_for :params do |o|
    = o.name ????
    = o.created_at ????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
= simple_form_for @banner |f|
  = f.input :name
  ...
  = f.simple_fields_for :params do |o|
    = o.input :name
    = o.input :created_at, :as => :date
```

But I'm not sure why you can need an input for created_at. Anyway, the documentation with examples is at [their Github page](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

To just show the value there is an `object` method

```
= simple_form_for @banner |f|
  = f.object.name
  ...
  = f.simple_fields_for :params do |o|
    = o.object.name
    = o.object.created_at.strftime('%x %X') # strftime just to format
```

Comment: I would like to "echo" the value not input object. So how to get @banner.name from f as string.